# Get the referenced node ID

Tags: nodes

I have a content type (a) referenced to another content type (b) by url widget, how can I get the ID of the referenced node (b)?
Thanks.

Comment: In what context do you want the nid ?

Comment: i need to get the node id for getting it's fields values and using them in node(a) fields

Comment: So you probably want to write a module and implement some custom code in [this hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) for example.

Comment: what function can fulfill (get the nid for referenced node)?

Comment: There's no function. You have to retrieve it with your own code from the `$build` variable. Please read the doc in the page referenced above.

Comment: are you now asking this in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27504/get-the-nid-from-url ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get node id using :

```
$nid = $node->field_reference['und'][0]['nid'];
```

And you can check it out from this:

```
drupal_set_message($nid);
```