# Get the NID from url

Tags: nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a node ID from the URL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6638/get-a-node-id-from-the-url)

I have two content types which one referenced to another by url widget, when i click on the link the node id passing with the url.
How can i get this nid from the url?
Is there some function for that?
Thanks

Comment: duplicate ? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/6638/2916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to use the nid of the node reference field inside a node template, you could grab it as `$node->FIELDNAME[0]['nid']` (D6 anyway, add an ['und'] or something similar in the mix for D7 :)  Otherwise, a lot of other examples are given in the article @refineo references above.